# Cambio de formato fecha para grabar y recuperar de MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

En una aplicación web bajo `jQuery`, estoy usando `datepicker` de `jQuery UI`.

Al `datepicker` le aplico una configuración regional de modo que la fecha la entregue en formato `dd/mm/yyyy`.

El usuario selecciona una fecha en el `datepicker`, la cual envío por `Ajax` a `php` para que sea grabado en `MySQL` y luego, a través de otro `Ajax` recupero la fecha que se ha grabado.

Por ejemplo, el usuario selecciona `18/11/2016` en `datepicker`, pero en `MySQL` al grabar esta fecha, queda como `000-00-00`; es como que no entendió la fecha y grabó un `0`.

Para resolver lo anterior, en el `php` que recibe la fecha, hice lo siguiente:

```
$fechaz = $_POST["fecha"];
$partes = array();
$partes = explode("/",$fechaz);
$arreglo = array($partes[2], $partes[1], $partes[0]);
$nueva_fecha = implode("-", $arreglo);

$con = conectar();

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO fechas (fecha) VALUES ('$nueva_fecha')";
$q1 = mysqli_query( $con, $sql1
```

De esta forma, ahora en `MySQL` queda grabado `2016-11-18`.

Al recuperar esta fecha de `MySQL` en el siguiente `Ajax`, y desplegarlo en otro `datepicker`, aparece una fecha que no corresponde `28/04/2022`. Traté de hacer lo mismo en el `php` que obtiene la fecha, usando `explode()` e `implode()`, pero no funciona con la fecha recuperada.

Al respecto, las preguntas son:

¿Existe una forma, a través de sentencias o funciones propias de `jQuery` que permitan, para el caso de grabar la fecha, transformar el formato del `datepicker` `dd/mm/yyyy` al formato que requiere MySQL `yyyy-mm-dd`, de modo que en el `php` no tenga que usar `explode()` e `implode()`?

Y relacionado con lo mismo, ¿Existe alguna sentencia o función que me permita transformar el formato de la fecha que viene de MySQL `yyyy-mm-dd` y llevarlo a `dd/mm/yyyy`, de modo de desplegarlo correctamente en el `datepicker`?

---

He tomado la sugerencia de @aldanux y me ha funcionado el grabar la fecha en `MySQL`, pero en presentar en el `datepicker` la fecha recuperada, no me funciona:

La invocación de grabar y recuperar la fecha es:

```
var fecha1 = $("#datepicker").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "grabar_fecha.php",
    data: "fecha=" + fecha1,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (respuesta) {
        console.log("GRABADO");
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: "recupera_fecha.php",
    data: "saludo=" + "buscar",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (res) {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", res.fecha);
    }
});
```

El `php` que graba quedó como:

```
require_once "funciones/conexiones.php";
$fechaz = $_POST["fecha"];
$f = str_replace('/', '-', $fechaz);
$fx = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($f));

$con = conectar();
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO fechas (fecha) VALUES ('$fx')";
$q1 = mysqli_query( $con, $sql1) or die("Problemas al ejecutar la consulta");
```

Este está grabando correctamente la fecha, en mi ejemplo `2016-11-18`

El `php` que recupera la fecha quedó como:

```
require_once "funciones/conexiones.php";

$saludo = $_POST['saludo'];
$con = conectar();

$sql = "SELECT max(id) as id, fecha FROM fechas";
$q = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$info = array();

while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
    $ident=$datos["id"];
    $fec=$datos["fecha"];
};

$fx = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fec));
$info['id'] = $ident;
$info['fecha'] = $fx;
echo json_encode($info);
```

Esto no está funcionando bien, pues la fecha que recupera es `1970-01-01`.

¿Qué es lo que falta?

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```js
$(function () {

    $("#tuFecha").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="tuFecha" />
```

> Nota: Este ejemplo funciona en `jsFiddle` pero aca no, pueden revisarlo?

Acá el demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/rn3w/WArtA/791/

Comment: La respuesta parece interesante, pero si pudieras explicar mas a detalle que hace este codigo, ayudarias mas al OP

Comment: @jasilva ahora es mucho mas claro

Answer (score 1):

Yo tengo un Helper para eso, más o menos de la siguiente forma :

```
/**
* Función que invierte el formato de la fecha
*
* @param string $fecha.
* @param string $parametro si no se envia un segundo valor,esta variable tiene predeterminado un guion '-'.
* @return string
*/
static function fechaInvertida($fecha = '', $parametro = '-') {

    if ($fecha == '') {

        return date ( 'Y' . $parametro . 'm' . $parametro . 'd', $fecha );

    } else {

        $fechaTipoFormato = self::fechaTipoFormato ( $fecha, $parametro );

        if ($fechaTipoFormato [4] == '-' || $fechaTipoFormato [4] == '/') {

            return date ( 'd' . $fechaTipoFormato [4] . 'm' . $fechaTipoFormato [4] . 'Y', strtotime ( $fechaTipoFormato ) );

        } elseif ($fechaTipoFormato [2] == '-' || $fechaTipoFormato [2] == '/') {

            return date ( 'Y' . $fechaTipoFormato [2] . 'm' . $fechaTipoFormato [2] . 'd', strtotime ( $fechaTipoFormato ) );

        }

    }

}
```

De este modo, solo le pasas la fecha y ella hace la inversión, indistintamente de si se pasa `2000-11-20` o `20-11-2000` devolverá la inversa.

Pero otra forma simple, sería usar el objeto `Datetime` de `php`. Con otra función tipo esta :

```
/**
 * @method fecha
 * @return date
 */
static function fecha ($fecha = '') {

    $fecha = new DateTime($fecha);

    return $fecha->format('d-m-Y');

}
```

En ambos casos las he usado para devolver el formato de `MySQL` a la fecha como se vé en latinoamerica.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer simplemente con la función [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php), conjunto con [date()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) de PHP.

**[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7d7519bf38fe59ddcd9bfa8d6e09fdebb0088ad)**

**EDIT:** No me he fijado de la barra `/` en la fecha:

Para convertir de `/` a `-` para la base de datos lo cambias con la función [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php) anteriormente:

```
function format_date_dd_mm_Y($date)
{
    return date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));
}

function format_date_Y_mm_dd($date)
{
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
}        

$fecha1 = '18/11/2016';
$fecha1 = str_replace('/', '-', $fecha1); // Cambia los '/' a '-'

$fecha2 = '2016-11-18';

echo format_date_Y_mm_dd($fecha1); // 18/11/2016 => 2016-11-18
echo format_date_dd_mm_Y($fecha2); // 2016-11-18 => 18/11/2016
```

Comment: Hola @aldanux, te comento que me funcionó la primera parte, la que graba. Con lo que me sugeriste, grabó bien la fecha en mysql. Lo que no logro hacer funcionar es la parte que recupera la fecha, pues con tu sugerencia, me devuelve "01/01/1970".

Comment: @JuncoFuerte - Como verás en la demo funciona tal cual... Me puedes decir cual fecha usas? En verdad no se en que puede fallarte...

Comment: Hola @aldanux, reinicie todo y ahora funcionó; no sé de donde estaba sacando esa fecha 01/01/1970; parece que correspondía a una fecha anterior que se había generado en una prueba anterior, supongo que debe ser porque se quedó almacenado en alguna caché; esa caché me ha dado muchos problemas, pues esta situación de estar viendo datos del pasado, me hace rebanarme los sesos tratando de encontrar el error. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda; que tengas buenas noches.

Comment: @JuncoFuerte - Esas situaciones sufrimos todos... :) Me alegro por ti! Saludos

Answer (score 1):

El widget de `Datepicker` de `jQuery UI`, tiene la opción de indicar [`altFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat) y [`altField`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField)

> **altFormat**: Este permite que un formato de fecha se muestre al usuario para fines de selección, mientras que un formato diferente se envía realmente detrás de las escenas.

**Nota**: vale la pena destacar que `altFormat` es el formato en que se visualizara la fecha en el selector especificado en `altField`.

Ejemplo de uso:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    altField: '#datepickerAlt',
    altFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
  
  //
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', '2016-11-18');
});
```

```css
.datepicker {
    position: relative;
}
.datepicker .datepicker-picker {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="datepicker">
  <label>Date:</label>
  <input type="text" class="datepicker-picker" id="datepicker">
  <input type="text" id="datepickerAlt">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1 de enero de 1970 es la fecha del día 0 para la computación en Linux.

Lo que evidencia que, desde mi punto de vista, lo que está mal es esta función en la recuperación de la fecha, ya que asumo que el campo de `MySQL` es timestamp:

```
$fx = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fec));
```

La cual la haría:

```
$fx = date('Y-m-d', $fec);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Este está grabando correctamente la fecha, en mi ejemplo 2016-11-18

Ok, el problema no es al guardar, sino al mostrar y, en tu código, lo tienes así:

```
$fx = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fec));
```

Cuando debería ser:

```
$fx = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($fec));
```

Ahora, supongo que tu código no es el real, porque en el ciclo solo haces asignaciones y hasta después intentas el cambio de formato. Lo mejor sería ver el código completo para saber lo que está pasando.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, me parece una interesante observación, ¿pero [es una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?

Comment: En la primera parte propongo la solución para obtener la fecha en el formato deseado; la segunda parte debería ser un comentario, incluso antes de haber respondido... pero aún no puedo comentar.